# Unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected token : from JSON data (AngularJS Api Request)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, get-request

So I'm getting this error and when I click on the link it shows next to it, it takes me to some json response:

```
{"link-canonical":"https:\/\/myanimelist.net\/anime\/1\/Cowboy_Bebop",.....}
```

I'm simply making a get request for an anime api. Apparently this colon in the json it retrieves is giving me the error..? I have no idea. My code for the request is definitely working but I just tried it out with another api url which worked fine.

This is the code for the request:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {

$scope.animeApi = $resource('http://jikan.me/api/anime/1', {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK"}, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

$scope.animeResult = $scope.animeApi.get({});
console.log($scope.animeResult);
```

}]);

Comment: why are you backslashing forward slash ?

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe thats the json that was returned in the response.

Comment: Well `{ method: "JSONP" }` is clearly wrong when the response comes as JSON

Comment: Why `JSONP`? The server sends `Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *`

Answer (score 0):

So you know what to do:

```
let str = {"link-canonical":"https:\/\/myanimelist.net\/anime\/1\/Cowboy_Bebop"};
let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str));
```

Comment: After magically ignoring the syntax error she should convert an object to a string and then parse this string back into an object? O.o

Comment: @Andreas syntax error? where? It's just not the valid JSON she got from that anime server.
After stringify: {"link-canonical":"https://myanimelist.net/anime/1/Cowboy_Bebop"}, (I hope you see the difference).
After parse she got a normal JSON object.